# Do null objects always have to be specified in latest c# code?

Tags: c#, resharper, .net-6.0

Please consider the following code:

```
public IList<string> DoSomething(SomeModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        return new List<string> {"model is null"};
    }

    ...
}
```

When I wrote the above code I keep getting a suggestion from Resharper that says "Expression is always false"

But I don't understand why because the expression here can most definitely be true if I pass a null object.

Now consider me calling this method:

```
DoSomething(null);
```

Here I get a warning from resharper that says Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.

Is there some new change in c# code that I'm just simply not aware of? We have to explicitly now specify null objects and if so what is the new "null" value?

Comment: It's [nullable references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).  You can make the type `SomeModel?` and it will tell the compiler that you do expect `null`.  It's basically a way to help reduce the chances of NREs.

Comment: So one thing I always loved with Resharper is that it would raise a warning when code could potentially be null. So I'm now worried that it is going to stop doing that because I did not put a ? at the end of an object. Is there a way to revert to old behavior?

Comment: Yes, you can turn it off with the `#nullable disable` per file and there's a way to turn it off for the entire solution, but honestly if you likely R# telling you when something could be null then converting your code to use nullable references will tell you when something might be null and when you don't have to worry about it being null.